# Why does Jupyter give me a ModSecurity error when I try to run Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am currently trying to build a webscraping program to pull data from a real estate website using Beautiful Soup. I haven't gotten very far but the code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

r=requests.get("http://pyclass.com/real-estate/rock-springs-wy/LCWYROCKSPRINGS/")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

When I try to print the data to at least see if the program is working I get an error message saying "Not Acceptable!An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security." How do I get the server to stop blocking my IP address? I've read some similar issues with other programs and tried clearing the cookies, trying different browsers, etc and nothing has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening since the webpage thinks that your a bot (and is correct), therefore you will get blocked when sending a request.

To "bypass" this issue, try adding the [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to the `headers` parameter in the `requests.get()` method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
}
url = "http://pyclass.com/real-estate/rock-springs-wy/LCWYROCKSPRINGS/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```